# false result when adding two unsigned (8-bit) and storing the result in a 9-bit unsigned

Tags: vhdl

I tried to implement a simple 8 bit adder with carry to test GHDL and gtkwave.
Unfortunately, the addition is somehow performed wrongly the VHDL code for the adder and the tb as well as the console output is attached.
Has anybody an idea why that error occurs?
if I remove the resize function and carry bit and shrink "myBuffer" to 8-bits the error still occurs.

Regards

adder:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    opA, opB :in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    c :out std_logic;
    result :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity adder;

architecture rtl of adder is
    --signals
    signal myBuffer : unsigned(8 downto 0);
begin
    add : process(clk, opA, opB)
    variable c_buf : std_logic := '0';
    begin  
        --on rising edge
        if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
            myBuffer <= resize(unsigned(opA) + unsigned(opB), myBuffer'length);
            --result <= myBuffer(7 downto 0);
            c_buf := myBuffer(8);
            assert c_buf = '1' report "carry detected" severity note;
            report "opA = "&positive'image(to_integer(unsigned(opA)));
            report "opB = "&positive'image(to_integer(unsigned(opB)));
            report "expected result = "&positive'image(to_integer(unsigned(opA)+unsigned(opB)));
            report "myBuffer = "&positive'image(to_integer(myBuffer));
            c <= c_buf;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

adder TB:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

--library adderLib;

entity adder_tb is
end entity;

architecture rtl of adder_tb is

    type data is array(3 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    --components
    component adder is
        port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        opA, opB :in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        c :out std_logic;
        result :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    --for all: adder use entity adderLib.adder;

signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal c : std_logic;
signal result : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal InOpA : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal InOpB : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
constant opA : data :=(0=>x"08",1=>x"09",2=>x"0A",3=>x"0B");
constant opB : data :=(0=>x"FF",1=>x"01",2=>x"02",3=>x"03");


begin

    --apply test signals & gen clock
   process
    variable iteration :integer := 0;
    begin
        for i in opA'range loop
            InOpA <= opA(i);
            InOpB <= opB(i);
            clk <= not clk;
            wait for 5 ns;
            clk <= not clk; 
            wait for 5 ns;
            report "iteration";
        end loop;
        
    end process;

    --connect component
    adierer: adder
        port map(
        clk => clk,
        opA => InOpA,
        opB => InOpB,
        c => c,
        result => result
        );

end rtl ;
```

TB output:

```
adder.vhd:26:13:@0ms:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@0ms:(report note): opA = 11
adder.vhd:28:13:@0ms:(report note): opB = 3
adder.vhd:29:13:@0ms:(report note): expected result = 14
../../../src/ieee/numeric_std-body.v93:2098:7:@0ms:(assertion warning): NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0
adder.vhd:30:13:@0ms:(report note): myBuffer = 0
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@10ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@10ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@10ns:(report note): opA = 10
adder.vhd:28:13:@10ns:(report note): opB = 2
adder.vhd:29:13:@10ns:(report note): expected result = 12
adder.vhd:30:13:@10ns:(report note): myBuffer = 14
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@20ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@20ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@20ns:(report note): opA = 9
adder.vhd:28:13:@20ns:(report note): opB = 1
adder.vhd:29:13:@20ns:(report note): expected result = 10
adder.vhd:30:13:@20ns:(report note): myBuffer = 12
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@30ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@30ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@30ns:(report note): opA = 8
adder.vhd:28:13:@30ns:(report note): opB = 255
adder.vhd:29:13:@30ns:(report note): expected result = 7
adder.vhd:30:13:@30ns:(report note): myBuffer = 10
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@40ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@40ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@40ns:(report note): opA = 11
adder.vhd:28:13:@40ns:(report note): opB = 3
adder.vhd:29:13:@40ns:(report note): expected result = 14
adder.vhd:30:13:@40ns:(report note): myBuffer = 7
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@50ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@50ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@50ns:(report note): opA = 10
adder.vhd:28:13:@50ns:(report note): opB = 2
adder.vhd:29:13:@50ns:(report note): expected result = 12
adder.vhd:30:13:@50ns:(report note): myBuffer = 14
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@60ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@60ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@60ns:(report note): opA = 9
adder.vhd:28:13:@60ns:(report note): opB = 1
adder.vhd:29:13:@60ns:(report note): expected result = 10
adder.vhd:30:13:@60ns:(report note): myBuffer = 12
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@70ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@70ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@70ns:(report note): opA = 8
adder.vhd:28:13:@70ns:(report note): opB = 255
adder.vhd:29:13:@70ns:(report note): expected result = 7
adder.vhd:30:13:@70ns:(report note): myBuffer = 10
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@80ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@80ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@80ns:(report note): opA = 11
adder.vhd:28:13:@80ns:(report note): opB = 3
adder.vhd:29:13:@80ns:(report note): expected result = 14
adder.vhd:30:13:@80ns:(report note): myBuffer = 7
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@90ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@90ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@90ns:(report note): opA = 10
adder.vhd:28:13:@90ns:(report note): opB = 2
adder.vhd:29:13:@90ns:(report note): expected result = 12
adder.vhd:30:13:@90ns:(report note): myBuffer = 14
adder_tb.vhd:48:13:@100ns:(report note): iteration
adder.vhd:26:13:@100ns:(assertion note): carry detected
adder.vhd:27:13:@100ns:(report note): opA = 9
adder.vhd:28:13:@100ns:(report note): opB = 1
adder.vhd:29:13:@100ns:(report note): expected result = 10
adder.vhd:30:13:@100ns:(report note): myBuffer = 12
./adder_tb:info: simulation stopped by --stop-time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues heres

1. You are seeing the reported mybuffer to be one calculation behind because of the way signals are assigned. When you assign a signal eg:`a <= b`; You are only sheduling the assignment to occur at the end of the current delta cycle. Until then, all reads will return the current value of the signal, and not the new one. Variables, however, are updated immediately. If you want to check the expected result in the same delta cycle, you should use a variable instead. (also ideally, you would report the actual and expected values in the testbench, not the DUT).
2. You are getting no carry because an 8bit + 8bit unsigned returns an 8 bit result. In your code you have done

```vhdl
myBuffer <= resize(unsigned(opA) + unsigned(opB), myBuffer'length);
```

This is an 8 bit result extended to 9 bits, hence the MSB will always be 0. To implement the carry, you need to extend at least one operand to the length of the result. Addition in VHDL will always extend all operands to the length of the longest. the simpliest way is to append a '0' to the front of one operands because this is unsigned:

myBuffer <= unsigned('0' & opA) + unsigned(opB);

3. You are using positive'image. If the result or any of the value are 0 then the simulation will throw an error. Use integer or natural instead.

Comment: ah now I remember reading something about the difference in the assignment of variables and signals inside a process thanks!! It works now btw. and also thanks for the tips regarding the unsigned addition and positive'image, very interesting !